# Can we use a gerund after the verb "allow"?

Tags: gerunds

I have these sentences:

- *You know they don't allow eating and drinking in here.*
  (From Oxford practice Grammar, Advanced)
- *We don't allow smoking in the hall.*
  (From Oxford dictionary)

How can we know that the -ing forms are not used as verb but as a noun?

Comment: Yes the sentences are correct. When an -ing word is used for an activity,  that's how we know it's being used as a noun (a gerund).

Comment: @BillyKerr **Gerunds are always verbs** heading Verb Phrases whose entire clause is used in syntactic roles requiring a Noun Phrase, typically a subject, object, or predicate nominative. Witness: ***“Smoking cigarettes** is just like **slowly killing yourself.”*** Notice how those *-ing* verbs accept object complements and manner adverbs, something nouns never do. (They also reject adjectives.) Although NPs in English can be infinitive clauses and gerund-participial clauses, that in no way makes those clauses somehow become nouns. They aren't; they're still 100.00% verbs all the way through.

Comment: @tchrist - What?  Were did I say gerunds are nouns or not verbs? I said "used as nouns".

Comment: @BillyKerr But they aren't "used as nouns". If they were used as nouns then like nouns they would accept pluralization and adjectives as modifiers but reject adverbs as modifiers and noun phrases as complements—instead of the other way around. They're actual clauses headed by a nonfinite verb that are being used as Noun Phrases in the formal sense of that term, which is quite different from being "used as a noun". Perhaps viewed from a ten-mile altitude that's a common first approximation, but even if so it's a perilous shorthand that still risks hiding the real situation—in my humble opinion.

Comment: @Madhi, take the word and drop what comes before it: Eating and drinking are not allowed here. Does that work? Yes.  **For learning and practical purposes**: eating and drinking are the subjects of the sentence and are gerund nouns. Fancy linguists will call those "noun phrases" but I do not.

Comment: @Lambie There's no such thing as "a gerund noun", which is an oxymoron. Please don't answer in comments.

Comment: @tchrist A gerund functions as  noun, so I call 'em gerund nouns. "Do noun things with it", too, which includes using the words as a compound subject in a sentence. The one case you didn't mention. Students learn without fancy stuff. That's why linguists should teach English.

Comment: @Lambie Being a subject like this never makes a phrase into a noun because a subject is a syntactic constituent and not a part of speech. Given how you’ve mixed up parts of speech with grammatical role/functions, I beg you: please stop using the word ‘gerund’ because your misuse of it can only confuse learners. You cannot for example apply an adjective to a gerund, only an adverb, because it’s only ever a verb. ‘Gerund’ is neither a part of speech nor an inflectional category, and blurring those all together with actual grammatical functions can only make confusing things worse. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can we know that the *‑ing* forms are not used as a verb but as a noun?

The only way you can tell whether an *‑ing* word is actually a noun or a verb is to see whether you can:

1. Do "noun things" to it, like:
   (A) modify it with an adjective "a big X-ing", or
   (B) use it in noun-only constructions such as "the X-ing *of* Y" where you connect two noun phrases with a preposition.
2. Do "verb things" to it, like:
   (C) modify it with a manner adverb like "Y-ly X-ing", or
   (D) use it with an object complement like "X-ing the Y".

However, this doesn't matter at all. Believe it or not, you do not need to know this.

All you need to learn is what things the verb *allow* can accept following
it, not whether each possible use of this or that random *‑ing* word
following it is a noun or a verb or an adjective. That never matters at
all.

To that end, the allowable predicate frames for *allow* are shown [here in
its Lexico entry](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/allow). And for your
purposes, what *allow* accepts really boils down to either one or two
object complements, both of which are always noun phrases.

- When there are **two** object complements, the first noun phrase
  represents the person being allowed to do something and the second noun
  phrase is an infinitive clause saying what that person is being allowed to
  do. (This works **almost** like the verb works in *let someone do
  something*, except that with *allow* the *to* particle must be explicit in
  *allow someone **to** do something*.)
- When there is only **one** object complement, this is a noun phrase
  naming just what it is that's being allowed, as in *allow horses* or *allow
  horse racing* or *allow racing horses*. This single noun phrase cannot be an infinitive clause, but it **can** be a
  gerund-participial clause with an *‑ing*  verb heading it, as in *allow
  doing something* like *allow smoking a cigarette or two during your lunch
  break*.

All these examples following are grammatical. The first three examples and example (9) all
take two object complements, while the rest all take just one object
complement. Sometimes these complements are nonfinite clauses headed by a
verb; other times they're noun phrases that are headed by a noun or are
just a personal pronoun by itself in object case such as *you* or *me* or
*him* or *her*.

1. We cannot let you race your turtles here. (*race* is a verb here)
2. You are not allowed to race your turtles here. (*race* is a verb here)
3. We cannot allow you to race your turtles here. (*race* is a verb here)
4. We cannot allow racing turtles slowly here. (*racing* is a verb here)
5. We cannot allow racing slow turtles here. (*racing* is a verb here)
6. We cannot allow the racing of slow turtles here. (*racing* is a noun here)
7. We cannot allow slow racing turtles here. (*racing* is a noun here)
8. We cannot allow slow turtles racing here. (*racing* is a verb here)
9. We cannot allow slow turtles to race here. (*race* is a verb here)
10. We cannot allow slowly racing slow turtles down our racetrack. (*racing* is a verb here)
11. We cannot allow turtle racing here. (*racing* is a noun here)
12. We cannot allow more time for turtle racing. (*racing* is a noun here)
13. We cannot allow more time for turtles racing so slowly. (*racing* is a verb here)
14. We cannot allow more time for racing slow turtles. (*racing* is a verb here)
15. We cannot allow your slow racing turtles any more time to finish the race. (*racing* is a noun here)
16. We cannot allow your turtles any more time to finish slowly racing down our course. (*racing* is a verb here)

As you see, I've gone to the trouble of adding a few extra words around any
*‑ing* words to help make it clear whether the complementary noun phrase's
head is a noun or a verb. I did this only because you asked, not because it
matters at all. That's because, just as I said starting out, whether an *‑ing* word
happens to be a noun or a verb doesn't make any difference when it comes to
knowing which sorts of predicate frames are grammatical with *allow*.